# How to add a link into this javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, addition

This script provides 4 images on a certain hour, now I want to add a link to each of those images to a website, is that possible and if so how can i do that?

Thanks for your time.

```html
<script>
  var current = new Date()
  var day_night = current.getHours()
  //if (day_night<=12)
  if (day_night >= 6 && day_night <= 11)
    document.write("<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='morning' class='morning'>")
  else
  if (day_night >= 11 && day_night <= 17)
    document.write("<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='day' class='day'>")
  else
  if (day_night >= 17 && day_night <= 23)
    document.write("<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='evening' class='evening'>")
  else
    document.write("<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='night' class='night'>")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a href links into you html. Put your link into ' ' of href=' '.

```
   <script>
        var current= new Date()
var day_night=current.getHours()
//if (day_night<=12)
if (day_night >= 6 && day_night <= 11)
    document.write("<a href='your link here'><img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='morning' class='morning'></a>")
else
if (day_night >= 11 && day_night <= 17)
    document.write("<a href='your link here'<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='day' class='day'></a>")
else
if (day_night >= 17 && day_night <= 23)
    document.write("<a href='your link here'<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='evening' class='evening'></a>")
else
    document.write("<a href='your link here'<img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='night' class='night'></a>")
        </script>
```

Comment: Hey ikiK, thanks for your reply, when i use the code the image does not show up anymore and also there is no link to click on

Comment: @Dan Read my edit i tested it it works. maybe you tried with href links wraped in double quotes. They need to be in single ' --- '. Also if you want link to be out side of picture just move closing </a> in front of opening <img. And put some text. Like this: <a href='your link here'>TEST</a><img...   I put link on picture to be clickable.

Comment: played around a bit, with this code ...   document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'><img src='img/spacer.svg' alt='night' class='night'>") the image show up and is clickable. Is this a correct way to do it? and i dont know if the script still works...

Comment: Well thanks for your time, you saved me ;) Now i can go on. Thanks again!